# Timeout WebSocket connections in aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My WebSocket server implementation is open to the world, but the client is required to send an authenticate message after the connection was established or the server should close the connection.

How can I implement this in aiohttp? It seems, I need to do the following things:

1. Create an `on_open` method for every socket connection: I can't find a way (similarly to on_open in Tornado) to create such event.
2. Create a timer: asyncio's `sleep` or `call_back` methods of the main event loop may be used. But I can't find a way to send the WebSocketResponse to the callback function:

   `await asyncio.sleep(10, timer, loop=request.app.loop)`
3. Closing the connection if not authenticated

This is what I had before with Tornado:

```
def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.timeout = ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(
        datetime.timedelta(seconds=60),
        self._close_on_timeout
    )

def remove_timeout_timer(self):
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().remove_timeout(self.timeout)
    self.timeout = None

def on_message(self, message):
    if message = 'AUTHENTICATE':
        self.authenticated = True
        self.remove_timeout_timer

def _close_on_timeout(self):
    if not self.authenticated:
        if self.ws_connection:
            self.close()
```

Here is what I have using aiohttp for setting up a timer:

```
async def ensure_client_logged(ws):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)  # wait 3 seconds
    await ws.send_str('hello')

async def ws_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()

    asyncio.ensure_future(ensure_client_logged(ws), loop=request.app.loop)
```

But the code is running in a blocking way, meaning the server becomes unresponsive while it is sleeping.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `async with async_timeout.timeout(3): await ws.receive()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish a deadline for the authentication procedure. [`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) is a convenient way to do that:

```
async def ws_handler(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    loop.create_task(handle_client(ws))

async def handle_client(ws):
    try:
        authenticated = await asyncio.wait_for(_authenticate(ws), 10)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        authenticated = False
    if not authenticated:
        ws.close()
        return
    # continue talking to the client

async def _authenticate(ws):
    # implement authentication here, without worrying about
    # timeout - the coroutine will be automatically canceled
    # once the timeout elapses
    ...
    return True  # if successfully authenticated
```

Comment: But how do I pass the ws_handler? As in Tornado, the handlers are **NOT** classes. I will edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: @bman Thanks. And how does authentication happen, where is the code that sets `self.authenticated` to true?

Comment: I still haven't implemented that part. But it would be using a defaultdict property in the application. Something like this: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=websocket#how-to-programmatically-close-websocket-server-side

Comment: Appreciate the updated answer. That's still not what I am trying to accomplish. The connection should stay open only for 10 seconds unless if user send the authenticate message. (Please look at the tornado example)

Comment: @bman Unfortunately I don't use Tornado, so I don't understand it in details. However, the amended answer should do exactly that - if the user doesn't authenticate in 10 seconds, the connection is closed (in the part under `if not self.authenticated: ...`).

Comment: I think that won't fix my problem, because it prevents the server from receiving new messages. Let me update my answer by using your approach to show you what I mean

Comment: @bman Then the code should be moved to a separate coroutine spawned with `create_task`, so it doesn't block `ws_handler`. I've now updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working example for the benefits of the future users:

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio

async def wait_for_authentication(ws, app):
    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == web.WSMsgType.TEXT and msg.data == 'AUTHENTICATE':  # Implement your own authentication
            await ws.send_str('WELCOME')
            return True
        else:
            await ws.send_str('NOT AUTHENTICATED')


async def authenticate(ws, app) -> bool:
    try:
        authenticated = await asyncio.wait_for(wait_for_authentication(ws, app), 5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        authenticated = False

    if not authenticated:
        await ws.send_str('The AUTHENTICATE command was not received. Closing the connection...')
        await ws.close()
        return False


async def ws_handler(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    await request.app.loop.create_task(authenticate(ws, request.app))

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type != web.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            continue

        await ws.send_str(msg.data)

def init():
    app = web.Application()

    app.router.add_get('/', ws_handler)

    return app

web.run_app(init())
```